# holoviews can't find flexx when using a Dimension value_format callback

Tags: holoviews

I am attempting to learn HoloViews within my ipython notebook and have run into an issue related to using a custom value_format for my kdims Dimension object.  Right now, my xformat routine is basically a no-op but I want to experiment with transposing the default tick labels to reduce the number of ticks on my x-axis, however, I need to get it to work as is before I move on to that.

Here is my code:

```
%%output size=200
%%opts Curve [width=600 height=250] {+framewise}
%%opts Curve.Load.Ticket (color='red')

def xformat(x):
    return x

kdims=hv.Dimension('Day Section', label='Week Day and Hour', value_format=xformat)

tload = hv.Curve(simple_pd,vdims=[('Max Ticket Load', 'Maxiumum Ticket Load')],kdims=kdims,group='Load',label='Ticket')
tload
```

The tload element renders, however, I get a warning that says:

```
WARNING:root:main: Day Section dimension formatter could not be converted to tick formatter. Ensure Flexx is installed ("conda install -c bokeh flexx" or "pip install flexx")
```

I verified that flexx is installed in my environment:

```
!conda list flexx
!conda list holoviews

# packages in environment at /opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35:
#
flexx                     0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
# packages in environment at /opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35:
#
holoviews                 1.10.7                     py_0    pyviz
```

Fairly confused by this warning.  Hopefully someone can shed some light on what might be wrong in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a compatibility issue with the most recent flexx release, for now I'd recommend downgrading to flexx 0.4.1 with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge flexx=0.4.1
```