# Dimension value_format callback not working properly

Tags: holoviews

This is a new question related to a previous question I asked: 
[holoviews can't find flexx when using a Dimension value_format callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52559603/holoviews-cant-find-flexx-when-using-a-dimension-value-format-callback)

Thanks to downgrading my version of flexx, I am no longer getting the warning message.  However, the callback function is not working.  Here is the code:

```
%%output size=200
%%opts Curve [width=600 height=250] {+framewise}
%%opts Curve.Load.Ticket (color='red')

def xformat(x):
    # update the default tick label to append an 'a'
    new = x + 'a'
    return(new)

kdims=hv.Dimension('Day Section', label='Week Day and Hour', value_format=xformat)

tload = hv.Curve(simple_pd,vdims=[('Max Ticket Load', 'Maxiumum Ticket Load')],kdims=kdims,group='Load',label='Ticket')
tload
```

When I run with the above code, I expect to see the same amount of x axis tick labels, however, each label should have an 'a' appended to the end.  However, what I am seeing is no rendering of the element at all in my notebook.  I have tried a number of variations of modifying the value, and the same thing happens.

[image: screen cap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, the issue appears to be the use of the variable name new in the xformat function.  If I change the name of the variable it works fine.  It doesn't appear as though new is a reserved work in python though, so I am not sure why its causing a problem.

Note that using the matplotlib extension does not have the same problem, only Bokeh.